# How do I make the collector, specifically for each person

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have a bot, then I want to make the bot can collect a message, then reply if he detect a spesific word, but the problem is my bot keep creating new collector if someone type the `tekong`, so when the bot detect the word it will gonna respond twice, depend on how many collector are created. How do I make the bot so that 1 person can only create 1

Here's my code

```
client.on("message", (message) => {

    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('tekong')) {
        message.channel.send('Bot is collector messages...')

        let filter = m => m.content.includes('test') && m.author.id === '744882468741709824'
        
        let collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {max: 1})

        collector.on('collect', indonesia => {
            console.log(indonesia.content);
        })

        collector.on('end', m => {
            console.log(`Collected ${m.size} items`)
            if (m.size === 1) {
                message.channel.send('Congratulations your enchantments is works!')
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply make a Set ( Array would also be an option, but I prefer Set as its easier to delete entries):

```
let blocked = new Set();
```

Then inside your message event you can use:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('tekong')) {
     if(blocked.has(message.author.id)) return;
     blocked.add(message.author.id);
```

If you are done and want the user to allow to use the command again, you can simply use:

```
blocked.delete(message.author.id);
```